# Laravel pass variables to modal dialogue if id

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have 3 tables, `categories`, `items`, `relateditems`. Now I can display these 3 tables in the home page, so I can see category name and under it item title and under item title can see item related.

I want to show variables in modal dialogue, in home page I can display it with no issue but I want to show specific item with its related items due to its id,Now I can display only items in the modal but can't display related items

**Home.blade**

```
@foreach($ritems as $categoryId => $groupItems)
    <div>
        <p>
            @if (!empty($groupItems->first()->category))        
                {{ $groupItems->first()->category->category_name }}
            @else
                {{$categoryId}}
            @endif
        </p>
    </div>
    @foreach($groupItems as $item)
        <button id="Item_root" data-titlefield="{{$item->item_title}}" class="Item_root">
            <span>{{$item->item_title}}</span>
            <p> related:</p>
            @foreach($item->relateditems as $relatedItem)
                @if ($relatedItem->item) 
                    {{$relatedItem->item->item_title}}  
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </button>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**javascript**

```
<script>
    $(function(){  
        $('.Item_root').on("click", function () { 
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#title').text($(this).data('titlefield'));
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
   $ritems = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->with('category','relateditems', 'relateditems.item')->get()->groupBy('category_id');
```

**Model**

category model

```
 public function items() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'category_id');
  }
```

Item model

```
  public function category() 
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
 }

  public function relateditems() 
 {
return $this->hasMany('App\Relateditem', 'ritemf_id');     
 }
```

relateditem model

```
 public function item() 
  {  
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'riteml_id');
   }
```

Comment: what this return  `$ritems = (new Item())->relateditems()->get();`

Comment: @SupunPraneeth  Collection {#193 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @SupunPraneeth any help please?

Comment: why it's says 193 ? did you put a `where' clause ?

Comment: I put dd($ritems) is this correct?

Comment: so it's empty ? ok  can you check you have related items that match with  items ?, can you add some matching rows to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174115/discussion-between-ahktm-and-supun-praneeth).

Comment: so should I post an answer or you are gonna post one ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth yes please I will check it as its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our long discuss in the chat you have to use ajax for the model view:

```
$(function() {
  $(".Item_root").on("click", function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var itemid = $(this).data("item-id");

    $.ajax({
      url: "url/to/router/" + itemid,
      type: "get",
      success: function(d) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#title").text(btn.data("titlefield"));
        $("#related_item").html(d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and for get that related item you have to add controller function that something like this:

```
function getRelatedItems()
{
    $currentid = request('item_id');
    $nritems = Item::where('item_id', $currentid)->first()->relateditems()->get();
    foreach ($nritems as $rItem) {

        $ItemDetails = Item::find($rItem->riteml_id);


        echo '<div class="SuggestedItem_container"> 
            <label color="red" class="Checker_root Checker_red Checker_left"> 
            <input type="checkbox" class="Checker_input" value="on"> 
            <div class="SuggestedItem_nameContainer"> 
            <div> 
            <span id="related_item" class="SuggestedItem_name">' . $ItemDetails->Item_title . '</span> 

            <span class="SuggestedItem_price styles_small styles_base styles_spacing-base">related item price</span></div></div> 

            <div class="SuggestedItem_description styles_small styles_base styles_spacing-base"> 
            <span class="SuggestedItem_category styles_bold">related item category</span> 

            <span>related item details</span> 
            </div> 
            </label> 
            </div>';
    }


}
```

Good luck!

Comment: @AHKTM you are welcome. and since it's doesn't cost you anything, an upvote would be nice :)